# code re use/ re use class/ WPF

Tags: wpf, inheritance, code-reuse, reusability

I have the following code in a WPF application to show a digital clock:

```
    public DigitalClock()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StartClock();
    }

    private void StartClock()
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += tickevent;
        timer.Start();
    }
    private void tickevent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textblockClock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

}
```

}

This created a digital clock within a textblock.  I would like to re use this clock and put it on all windows within the application, but I feel copying and pasting the code 10 times is the wrong way to do it.

I'm very new to programming but want to learn best practices going forward.

Would someone be able to please point me in the direction of some learning material, or a video that covers what I want to do.  I've looked at inheritance videos but they seem less complicated than this with maybe only 1 method.

Any input/guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There is very little you can improve upon here.  Even if you encapsulated this code, you'd have to ref in your control (which would be kinda weird) or still have to subscribe to an event, which means you'd save two lines.  Don't worry about this kind of stuff as a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose it in a usercontrol and add that control into other windows.
[this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32825/How-to-Creating-a-WPF-User-Control-using-it-in-a-W) link will help you.

Comment: @taxer03, its an ok link, and goes into a bit more than the simple context you need, but the basics are what you need.  Create custom control (user Control or whatever), add the code, save it.  Then add to your form.